# Target a Object Variable in a different Class

Tags: class, c#-4.0

So, without posting my entire project in here, I will sum it up as best I can:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thing one = new Thing();
        one.addTimer(10);
        one.addTimer(4);
        one.addTimer(2);
        one.addTimer(8);

    }
}

class Counter
{
    private int Seconds;
    private int TimerNum;
    public Counter(int SecondsX)
    {
        Seconds = (SecondsX * 1000);
    }

    public void TimerCall(){
    Thread.sleep(Seconds);
    CounterCallBack();
    }

    public void CounterCallBack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer " + TimerNum + " Done");
        //Then the time is up the call back is executed
        //The issue I am having is how do I trigger the next timer for the list timers to go from hear automatically. It would send back TimerNum to Thing.Continue
    }

}

class Thing
{
    List<int> timers = new List<int>();

    public Thing()
    {

    }
    public void addTimer(new Timer(int SecondsToAdd))
    {
        timers.Add(SecondsToAdd);
    }
    public void StartTimers(){
    timers[0].TimerCall();
    }

    public void Continue(int LastRun){
    if(timers.count()-1>= LastRun){
    timers[LastRun].TimerCall();
    }
    }

}
```

So I need to access the Continue method from counter to kick off the next timer.
Or I need to find a way to do the same thing.
However, the user needs to be able to edit, add, and remove timers (Which happens from the `Program` class)

Remember that in my program (this is a simplified version) `Counter` is a timer Call and CallBack that runs asynchronously.

Is it even possible to do? Or do I need to scrap this approach and start from square one?

Also, I know this is rough, but this a project is for charity and I plan to clean it up once I get this prototype working. Also I am 16. So please, any help you can give would be well appreciated.

Comment: did you mean to do timers.Add(new Timer(SecondsToAdd)); and make the list timers of type Timer and not int? You are calling TimerCall() on an int and not a Timer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think I could do this by adding a method in Program that Runs Continue and make an object variable in Counter. However, that is just messy I am still hoping someone finds a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay It's a dirty answer but I am going to Use a dictionary to store the Object variables, and have an assessor method that is passed the ID of Correct set of timers, and the Index of the next timer to run. That then calls the next timer, and so on and so fort.
Dirty but functional for a Prototype.